# Opaque Objects with Lighting

Tags: objects, lighting

I currently have a model of an LED Light Ring, only the plastic piece on top of the LEDS can be transparent. All of the other parts have light coming through them, which is an issue. How do I make individual objects opaque so no light can go through them?

Comment: Are you using actual lights for your lighting, or emission surfaces?

Comment: I am just using actual lights.

Comment: I am only using one light currently and about to begin animating, when I place the light next to my led ring, light goes through pieces, how do I fix it? If you are available, we can contact through email and we could hop on a phone call.

Comment: Here is the link, https://www.dropbox.com/l/scl/AAA8vPrclyln4pqgTEu_UxgcSTKft4hp7GY I need every piece except the Top Gloss to be opaque.

Comment: Hey, Dropbox wants me to sign in and have access to all my contacts in order to view that file, and to be honest, I'd rather not agree to that. Do you mind uploading here instead? - https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/. Just drag your file into the box, agree to the terms, and paste the URL of this question into the box provided. After you click upload, it will give you a link, Edit your question and paste the link there.

Comment: Sounds good, waiting for file to upload now. It is nearly 200mb, should it take a long time to process? Do you have an email I can send it to, its been stuck on "Files may take some time to process" for the past 10 mins now.

Comment: Oh, too bad. They don't allow uploads over 50 mb. Hang on, my wife has dropbox, she'll get it for me.

Comment: Oh no worries! It is all good.

Comment: Hey. Ok, so the file lacked packed resources, and because of that it wouldn't let me edit anything (material-wise) because it was part of a missing "linked data block". The only thing I was able to tell was that enabling contact shadows stopped most of the light bleed, but I couldn't see anything showing through - likely due to the missing textures. That's all I can really recommend at this point. I unfortunately don't have any more time at the moment to look at it further, but perhaps later on I can have a better look at it. Sorry I couldn't be more help.

Comment: No worries, I appreciate your time and help.

Comment: Don't make the question depend on others downloading stuff. Edit your original post and add images and explain clearly the issue.